# Why does CFFile.ServerFile return the folder path when using Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I am uploading files to Amazon S3 like so:

```
<cffile action="upload" accept="image/jpeg, image/pjpeg" destination="s3://accessKeyID:awsSecretKey@bucket/X/Y/sample.jpg" filefield="ImageField" />
```

The above works fine and the `sample.jpg` file is in my S3 bucket located as `https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/X/Y/sample.jpg`

In the rest of my code I use `CFFILE.ServerFile` to get the name of the file uploaded which should just be `sample.jpg` (I tested it and it is just `sample.jpg` when upload locally to the server). However when uploading to S3 like in the code above, `CFFile.ServerFile` returns `X/Y/sample.jpg` as the name of the file which is wrong.

If I check the contents of `CFFILE.ServerFileExt` then that returns `jpg` correctly when uploaded locally or to S3.

Am I missing something?

Comment: There is no folder structure on S3. It's a flat file system so every folder and file is just a file. /X/Y/sample.jpg is the full filename even though we perceive this as a folder structure

Comment: Thank you haxtbh - I didn't realise that ColdFusion also saw it that way. In that case I'll just do `<cfset CFFILE.SERVERFILE = Trim(ListLast(CFFILE.ServerFile, "/")) />` to get `sample.jpg`. Should be safe right? I am asking ColdFusion to get the last element in a list where `/` is the delimiter

Comment: A simple getFileFromPath('X/Y/sample.jpg') would work.

Comment: @PMascari nice tip! so far getFileFromPath() is working nicely... but is it just basically doing a ListLast()? I ask so that I can be sure it won't fail in the future if the filename is weird.

Comment: I can't speak to the inner workings of the getFileFromPath() function but, yes, it looks to be doing the same as ListLast() in this case.